# Retrieve meta content by url

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-scraping

I have a script which allows to retrieve all sorts of information of a given url: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4QCt/141/)

As you can see the meta content is derived from the 'baseUrl' (at the begining of the script).
There is also a div (#links) for all the a href on that page (baseUrl).
My question: How do I get the meta content of the links instead of the baseUrl?

Answer (score 0):

What your script is doing is loading the main page and parsing out the data. In order to get the meta tags on the linked urls you need to basically run the script again with the link URLs instead of just your `baseUrl`. If you loop this indefinitely, you have basically built a web crawler.